# How to configure “open next or previous item” after delete in Microsoft Outlook Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I want to select the previous item on deleting an email. I know how to do this in Windows. I can't find File -> Options in Mac Outlook app.

I have checked the preferences as well but couldn't find the option. Can someone help? The only other option I see is to sort it by date in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Outlook for Mac doesn't provide such an option. The functionality is limited comparing to the Windows version of Outlook. If you do like this feature, let Microsoft know it: [Outlook Feedback/Outlook for Mac](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/293343-outlook-for-mac).